# Chat Client API: how to tell when a message arrived

Tags: c#, events

I am writing a chat server and client in C# and a client API.

I would like to know how to allow the user of the API to be aware when a new message arrived.

I could do

```
while(true){
    messages = clientAPI.getMessages();
    // do stuff
}
```

but then, it will receive several time the same message.

Thanks

Comment: We need to get more info! What kind of platform do you use (mobile, web, windows ...) and what is clientAPI (type)?

Comment: clientApi is a class I created myself. the platform is Windows

Comment: So than I would suggest to use events in that class instead of working with a loop. I'll post a sample.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach would be to use [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) to notify users when "things happen".

You could have a `MessageReceived` event of a custom type which provided the actual message, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information on what the client API is would [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) be a viable solution? It certainly is a perfect fit for this type of project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working under ASP.NET and have the appropriate infrastructure, I'd strongly recommend looking at the SignalR library.

[SignalR on ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: @taktak004 Understand!  Learning is good, but re-inventing the wheel isn't the most productive.

Answer (score 0):

I promised to post a simple event-sample. So your server-code should be something like this:

```
public class ClientApi
{

    public EventHandler SomethingHappened;

    public void StartWorkerMethod()
    {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (SomethingHappened != null)
                SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

So your client would use this as follows:

```
var clientApi = new ClientApi();
clientApi.SomethingHappened += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Something happened on the server!");
clientApi.StartWorkerMethod();
```

If you implement this inside a console application you'll see the result coming 10 times with waits between the events.